# Meteor: how to export a class and use in another file on server

Tags: javascript, function, class, meteor

I'm using Meteor and have created some classes on the server. How can I make them accessible when I want to declare them inside other files on the server?

For instance, I will be separating each class function into its own file as each one will be large. How can I initialise and use the class when I need it?
E.g.

Importing a file could be done like this

```
var User = require('./userclass.js');
var user = new User();
```

server/lib/classfile.js

```
class User {

    constructor(params) {

        this._firstName = params.firstName;
        this._lastName = params.lastName;
        this._email = params.email;
    }
}
```

server/file.js

```
var myVar = new User(someParams)
// this is undefined
```

Comment: Is your class file actually names "classfile.js" or "userclass.js"?   You problem may just be load order of the files, and not accessibility....

Comment: that is just an example of doing this in node, however, I am unfamiliar in how to do this in meteor

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define dependencies in Meteor using `require` -- meteor is somewhat expected to figure that out for you, however it is far from perfect, and for bootstrap code you would need to pay attention to the load order of the files (The Meteor documentation have a [section on load order](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp), you should read that, but in short files in `lib` are loaded first and all files are loaded in alphabetical order..

That being said, with the `class` feature being new in ES2015 it looks like a bug that classes are not properly exported by Meteor, but you can do a workaround for that.

The following works for me using Meteor version 1.2.0.2 ...

**lib/user.js**

```
class xUser {
    constructor(params) {
        console.log(params)
    }
    toString(){return "Hi";}
}
User = xUser   // this is avaiable in global space
```

**server/bootstrapcode.js**

```
var myVar = new User("Hello")
console.log(myVar.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I'd like to initialise the class only when it is needed, and not having it available globally.

Comment: You could always create your own scope object (like what node.js `require` implements) and just export and import modules as needed -- however that is not a standard functionality of Meteor.

Comment: module is not defined if I try to export it. module.exports = User;

Comment: There is no `module` or `export` in meteor - meteor automatically exports what is written to global scope within the file -- that is why the last line of user.js is `User = xUser;`